# Sound got extremely terrible after updating Realtek Audio Drivers

Tags: windows-10

Yesterday I've updated my Realtek HD Audio drivers and the sound just got so damn bad I can't even listen to it. I've tried reinstalling and everything.. Nothing seems to work to get my old sound back

Comment: Did you try rolling back the driver in device manager?

Comment: Yeah but the sound was the same.. Tried it multiple times

Comment: Do you have a recent restore point you can roll back to?

Comment: No, there’s no option to do that

Comment: We've not much to go on, but assume the settings changed somewhere. Check whether it's set to 48k or 44.1k, toggle, see which is best. Win10 has been known to handle 48k badly in some setups.

Comment: I've tried that too, is there any way I could make virtualization surround sound work in Realtek HD manager?

Answer (score 1):

From the speaker icon in the system tray, right click and choose Open Sound Settings -> Choose your output device -> Device properties -> Enhancements -> and make sure "Disable all sound effects" is checked.

Worked for me.